# vimeo iframe background video is unmuted upon video click using jquery, works fine on every devices, including macbooks but doesnt work on iphones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, vimeo

I am using Vimeo iframe background video.

I am toggling the URL parameter between "muted=0" and "`muted=1`" on user click, and it works as expected on every device, android phones, and iOS desktops, except on iOS mobile devices.

On IOS mobile devices, when the parameter changes to "`muted=0`", the video doesn't play, but plays again when toggled to "`muted=1`".

Can anyone suggest a way around it, please?